# Commutation of symmetric and skew-symmetric part of orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations, orthogonal-matrices

Can we claim that for an orthogonal matrix $A$ (satysfying $AA^T=I$),
its symmetric and skew-symetric parts are always commuting?

Symmetric part is calculated as $S=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$ and skew symmetric part as $K=\frac{1}{2}(A-A^T)$.

It's easy to show the claim for dimension $2$.

Also for dimension $3$ we can see commutation for orthogonal matrices with determinant equal to 1.
For a rotation matrix $R$ it's evident from the Rodrigues formula,
when $R=\color{blue}{I+(1-\cos\theta) V^2 }+ \color{green}{\sin\theta V }$ for some skew-symmetric matrix $V $.

Here commutation  follows because   symmetric part   and skew-symmetric part are expressed as polynomials of the same matrix $V $.

Is it possible to find similar explanation for higher dimensions of orthogonal matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can verify it using a direct computation:

$$ SK = \frac{1}{2} \left( A + A^T \right) \cdot \frac{1}{2} \left(A - A^T \right) = \frac{1}{4} \left( A^2 - AA^T + A^TA - \left( A^T \right)^2 \right) = \frac{1}{4} \left( A^2 - \left( A^T \right)^2 \right)$$
while
$$ KS = \frac{1}{2} \left( A - A^T \right) \cdot \frac{1}{2} \left( A + A^T \right) = \frac{1}{4} \left( A^2 + AA^T - A^TA - \left( A^T \right)^2 \right) = \frac{1}{4} \left( A^2 - \left( A^T \right)^2 \right)$$

where we used the fact that $AA^T = A^TA$ (as they both are equal to $I_n$). More generally, the symmetric and and skew-symmetric part of a matrix commute iff the matrix is normal and an orthogonal matrix is normal.

Comment: I didn't expect that it is so easy to show the claim by direct calculation. We see that commutation is evident. But .. can we also find a matrix $V$ such that $S$ and $K$ are polynomials of this matrix as it's often happens in the case of commutation?

Comment: @Widawensen: This is an interesting question which you should probably ask separately. The generalization of Rodrigues's formula (see https://www.emis.de/journals/BJGA/v18n2/B18-2-an.pdf) tells you that any orthogonal matrix with determinant one can be written as a polynomial in a skew-symmetric matrix $V$ and then the symmetric parts consists of the even powers while the skew-symmetric part consists of the odd powers and they clearly commute. However, finding $V$ is not trivial (it involves finding a logarithm of the original matrix).

Comment: Very useful paper and inspiring. I was hoping in fact for some extension of Rodrigues formula for higher dimensions when I was writing "Is it possible to find similar explanation for higher dimensions of orthogonal matrices?" Thank you Levap..

Answer (score 3):

We have $AA^T=A^TA=I.$ Hence

$$(A+A^T)(A-A^T)=A^2-AA^T+A^TA-(A^T)^2=A^2-I+I+(A^T)^2=A^2-(A^T)^2.$$

A similar computation gives

$$(A-A^T)(A+A^T)=A^2-(A^T)^2.$$

Comment: Can we claim additionally that these two matrices are polynomials of some matrix $V$ and even more,   are we capable to find this matrix?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably the characteristic of the underlying field is not $2$.

The orthogonality condition implies that $(S+K)(S-K)=4AA^T=4A^TA=(S-K)(S+K)$. Hence $S$ commutes with $K$.

Alternatively, note that the inverse of a matrix $A$ is a polynomial in $A$. This is a consequence of Cayley-Hamilton theorem. It follows that when $A$ is orthogonal, $A^T$ is a polynomial in $A$. In turn, $S$ and $K$ are polynomials in $A$ as well. Hence they commute.

Comment: Excellent.  Commutativity is visible  here from polynomials.  Only $4$ is not needed, it seems ?, in $4AA^T$ . We see additionally that we can identify these polynomials.